# Pass array to view without html encoding issue node js(handlebars)

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I am making a call to the yahoo finance api which is returning a csv. I then want to convert the csv file to an array which google charts can read. The issue is when I pass the array to the view it has a bunch of html encoded characters.

For example I want to pass the array:

```
[['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],['2004',1000,400],['2005',1170,460],['2006',660,1120],['2007',1030,540]]
```

But when the page is rendered it is throwing an error and the passed array looks like this:

```
[[&#x27;Year&#x27;, &#x27;Sales&#x27;, &#x27;Expenses&#x27;],[&#x27;2004&#x27;,1000,400],[&#x27;2005&#x27;,1170,460],[&#x27;2006&#x27;,660,1120],[&#x27;2007&#x27;,1030,540]]
```

Here is my index.js:

```
var router = require('express').Router();

function GetCompanyInformation(callback) {
    var request = require('request');
    request('http://table.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=orcl&a=0&b1&c=2010&d=0&e=1&f=2011&g=d&y=0&z=orcl', function (error, response, data) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            return callback(null,data);
        }
        return callback('An error has occurred.',null);
    })
}

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    GetCompanyInformation(function(err, data){
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Express',
            data : "[['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],['2004',1000,400],['2005',1170,460],['2006',660,1120],['2007',1030,540]]"
        });
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Here is my view:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <hr>
        <div id="stock-chart-container" class="col-lg-12">
            <h3>Item Name</h3>
            <hr>
            <div id="company-performance-chart"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{data}});

        var options = {
            chart: {
                title: 'Company Performance',
                subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('company-performance-chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    <!--RESIZE THE GOOGLE CHART (MAKES IT RESPONSIVE)-->
    $(window).resize(function(){
        drawChart();
    });
</script>
```

The value that needs to be passed over to the google charts needs to look like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Income', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
    ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
    ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
    ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
    ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
]);
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way?

@James When I pass it as an array i get this in the rendered view:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(Year,Sales,Expenses,2004,1000,400,2005,1170,460,2006,660,1120,2007,1030,540);
```

Comment: Your data property is a string, not an array (it starts with a double quote).

Comment: I have tried removing the quotes to make it an array it doesn't pass correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{{ }}}` instead of the `{{ }}`

Comment: May you explain why? It will surely help to improve this answer.